# Display chat data when no internet Connection like WhatsApp

Tags: ios, database, xcode, parse-platform, chat

I am developing a chap app, and using Parse as a backend everything working fine, now my client requirement is to load chat data while user have no internet connection. i don't have any idea how can i achieve this.

any help appreciable
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You have to store all your messages in local database. For this you can use sqlite or core data. For both conditions, with or without internet connection, you should fetch and display messages form database.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, Follow the below steps,

- When ever chat message recieve save in SQLite database.
- If images received saved in to document directory (inside the application folder)
- and save path as image path intoSQLite.
- So you can get data from SQLite even you are in offline.

To do above steps more sources are in internet and it will help you. :)

Answer (score 0):

Use NSFetchedResultsController for this.
Here is a tutorial of how you can implement it.

http://www.raywenderlich.com/999/core-data-tutorial-for-ios-how-to-use-nsfetchedresultscontroller